# $3.\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x,e_n\rangle=?$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

given that $\{e_i\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal sequence in a hilbert space $H$, and $x\ne 0\in H$. Then could any one tell me which of the following is true?

$1.\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x,e_n\rangle$ does not exist

$2.\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x,e_n\rangle=\|x\|$

$3.\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x,e_n\rangle=1$

$4.\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x,e_n\rangle=0$

I just know one relations about orthonormal sequence in Hilbert space
 $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle x,e_i\rangle|^2\le \|x\|^2$. Thank you for help.

Comment: You have a convergent series. What is the limit of the main term?

Comment: what is main term boss?

Comment: The term $|\left<x,e_n\right>|^2$.

Comment: i dont know :( :(

Comment: Just call that term $c_n$. You know that the infinite series $\sum_n c_n$ converges; what can you conclude about $\lim_{n\to\infty} c_n$?

Comment: :-ooooooooooooo yes the limit will be zot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Bessel's ineqaulity
$$
\sum_n|\langle x,e_n\rangle|^2\leq \Vert x\Vert^2
$$
so the series $\sum_i|\langle x,e_i\rangle|^2$ converges. Hence its terms tend to zero, and so does $\langle x,e_n\rangle$.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb, fixed